# Can't suppress deprecated warnings in php v5.3

Tags: php, error-handling

I've seemingly tried about every different suggestion provided through a couple hours of Google and stackoverflow searching to no avail, and I cannot seem to suppress a large sum of "Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in " errors presented at the top of my application, as well as Many "Warning: the magic method __get() (and __set()) must have public visibility and cannot be static in .  Thus far, I have added the following line and many different variations of it to my php.ini file:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED
```

I've also attempted a straight suppression of every single error:

```
error_reporting = ~E_ALL
```

To no avail either.  I've confirmed that it is correctly reading the php.ini file by adjusting other settings successfully.
I've also applied the error_reporting() function (with all different variations of what's provided above) within my scripts with no more luck.  Does the location of the reporting have anything to do with the suppression?  I've tried posting it at the top of the first file being loaded, also at the top of a required file that is getting called immediately upon executing the main script, no where does it seem to take it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with a number: http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

Everything but the two deprecateds would be `8191`.

**PS**. It's possible the app/framework/website you're watching/editing/creating sets the error reporting level to E_ALL. If so, it doesn't matter what you set in php.ini, because it's overridden later.

Comment: The error_reporting was located in many different files, and after sifting through 30-40 files, removing all instances of error_reporting() or including ~E_WARNING and ~E_DEPRECATED, the warnings and deprecated notices stopped.  Much thanks!

Comment: NP. Not a best practice: setting error reporting more than once. Well twice is allowed I guess (controllers all and templates none).

Comment: after switching from PHP 5.2 to 5.3, `E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE` needed to be changed to something like `E_ALL &~(E_DEPRECATED | E_NOTICE | E_STRICT)` as the value for error_reporting

Comment: I always have E_ALL. Always. Everywhere. On production `display_errors` is off, but I always want to know about all of them.